# Howto create ember data bindings between view controllers and components when creating Ember components programatically

Tags: ember.js

I'm struggling with creating a data binding with my EditorController and a component that is created programatically on view initialization. I would like create a binding between the "activeColor" property on my view's controller "EditorController" and my "ColorPickerComponent"'s color attribute. 
I've got the following code for my component initialization, it displays the controllers color but it's not bound to the controller property in anyway. How do I manage to bind the values together?

```
App.SidebarView = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()
    controller = @get('controller')
    @pushObject(App.ColorPickerComponent.create({color: controller.get('activeColor') }))
```

## UPDATE 1

I've managed to solve the bindings by using the following code. It however seems a bit sketchy . Is there any other known way of doing this?

```
App.SidebarView = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  init: ->
  @_super()
  @pushObject(App.ColorPickerComponent.create({colorBinding: '_parentView.context.activeColor' }))
```

## UPDATE 2

Thanks alexspeller @ #emberjs for providing a clean solution to this http://jsfiddle.net/YGNG4/3/

Comment: Just a fyi, `parentController` isn't a real thing, in that you could have almost put any name in there and it would have worked, a la, http://jsfiddle.net/YGNG4/4/, will you please put your answer below and mark it as accepted, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, alexspeller for providing a clean solution to this http://jsfiddle.net/YGNG4/3/

```
App.SidebarView = Ember.ContainerView.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()
    controller = @get('controller')
    @pushObject(App.ColorPickerComponent.create({parentController: controller}))
```

and kingpin2k for pointing out that the parentController is not a real a real thing or a ember naming convention, it could be set as anything else.